# End the n+1 issue through Link Query to join multiple tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, controller

I have a Linq query that I currently pull out a table and then in the view I filter 5 joins down to a specific value.  This as many of you know would greatly increase the amount of time for my view to load as for each record has to run its own individual query for each of the joins.  I want to switch the joins in to the Linq query, so it is all in one query but I am having trouble.

Here is my controller code:

```
private IEnumerable<Ticket> FindTechTickets(Guid ticketStatusId)
{
       Guid g = Guid.Parse(Session["LoggedUserID"] as string);

       return db.Tickets
              .Include(t => t.TicketNotes)
              .Where(t => t.TechnicianId == g).Where(t => t.TicketStatusId == ticketStatusId)
              .OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketNumber)
              .ToList();

}
```

And here is my view code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(m => m.TicketNumber))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNumber)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OpenDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OpenUser.FullName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.CategoryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNotes.OrderBy(t => t.TicketNoteDate).Last().TicketNoteDate)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNotes.OrderBy(t => t.TicketNoteDate).Last().UserNote.FullName)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="overflow:auto; width:300px;">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TicketNotes.OrderBy(t => t.TicketNoteDate).First().Note)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Open/Edit", "EditTechTicket", new { id = item.TicketId, returnUrl = "TechOpenTickets", ViewBag.page})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

and here is my attempt at changing the Linq query:

```
var ts = 
          from t in db.Tickets
          Join tn in db.TicketNotes on t.TicketId equals tn.TicketId
          Where(t => t.TechnicianId == g).Where(t => t.TicketStatusId == ticketStatusId)
          OrderByDescending(t => t.TicketNumber)
          select new
          {

          }
```

The problem is am getting build errors on almost every line.  Starting with the Join line.

This is the link that I am getting the information from:

[Pulling out different columns from different tables using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5408876/pulling-out-different-columns-from-different-tables-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

1. It seems you're missing some parentheses.
2. `Join` is not the method you're looking for. It does something entirely different. You want `Include`.

Comment: Chris, I have include in my original code at the top.  How would I then be able to pull specific records out of the other table with an include statement?  I tried to pull specific records out with the Include also and to no avail.

Comment: All include does is join the other table. You can't really filter it in place. It will simply bring in all the associated records from the database, and then when you later use something like `Where`, it will filter in memory rather than requerying.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought.  However, doesn't it have to do a separate filter for each record? which slows it down?  That is why I am trying to move that out of my view in to my Linq statement.

Comment: No, that's the whole point of include. It does a join to bring in the other tables related data, so no further database queries are needed. N+1 happens when you *don't* do this, and then do something like iterate over that non-included set of data.